# PHP Generate Array with number of month and year display

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, datediff

I have two dates of the form:

> Start Date: 2010-12-24
>   End Date: 2011-10-06 (today)

Now I need to generate an array for this group by month from the above start date and end date:

```
$arr_month['oct_11'] = array(
   'month'   => 'October 2011'
 );
 . 
 . 
 .
$arr_month['feb_11'] = array(
   'month'   => 'Feb 2011'
 );

$arr_month['jan_11'] = array(
   'month'   => 'January 2011'
 );

$arr_month['dec_10'] = array(
   'month'   => 'December 2010'
 );
```

As you can see the table should be got 11 rows in the table if I use this array to generate a table.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do.  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I want to generate a table using the array. user only input the from and end date. I want it group by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start_date = '2010-12-24';
$end_date = '2011-10-06';

function getMonthArray($start_date, $end_date){
    $start_timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $start_date));
    $end_timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $end_date));

    $start_month_timestamp = strtotime(date('F Y', $start_timestamp));
    $current_month_timestamp = strtotime(date('F Y', $end_timestamp));

    $arr_month = array();

    while( $current_month_timestamp >= $start_month_timestamp ) {
        $arr_month[strtolower(date('M_y', $end_timestamp))] = date('F Y', $end_timestamp);
        $end_timestamp = strtotime('-1 month', $end_timestamp);

        $current_month_timestamp = strtotime(date('F Y', $end_timestamp));
    }

    return $arr_month;
}

$arr_month = getMonthArray($start_date, $end_date);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Ls6YL)

Comment: Your guys is awesome! really fast in response! respect

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = "2010-12-24";
$end = "2011-10-06";

function enumerate($start,$end) {
        $start = strtotime($start);
        $end = strtotime($end . "+1 month");
        $range = range($start,$end,60*60*24*31);
        $formatted = array();
        foreach($range as $date) {
        $key = strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",date("M Y",$date)));
        $formatted[$key] = array(

                        "month" => date('M Y',$date),
                        "amount" => "365"
                );
        }       
        return $formatted;
}

var_dump(enumerate($start,$end));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$start = strtotime(substr_replace('2010-12-24', '01', -2));
$end = strtotime('2011-10-06');

$time = $start;
$arr_month = array();
while ($time <= $end) {
    $arr_month[strtolower(date('M_y', $time))]['month'] = date('F Y', $time);
    $time += date('t', $time) * 24 * 60 * 60;
}

var_dump($arr_month);
```

http://ideone.com/ozLOx